# Android - selected item position in a listview

Tags: android, listview

How can I retrieve the positions of the selected item in a multichoice listView?
The `getSelectedItemPosition` method returns only the first one.

Answer (score 10):

There is at most one *selected* item in a `ListView`.

If your `ListView` is `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` or `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`, you can use `getCheckedItemPositions()` to get the *checked* ones.

Comment: Tnahk you for your answer.
the method returns a SparseBooleanArray. How can i use this object to find the positions ?

Comment: I have not used SparseBooleanArray. From the API, it appears you iterate over the size(), and for each index, you get the "key", which is a ListView position, and then get the value, which will be the boolean checked state of that position.