# importing phonebook contacts to application with checkboxes eachrow

Tags: android, contacts

How can I import contacts from phone book to my android appplication with a cheackbox on each row.  Further I want to move those contacts to databse... As in this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lg8B.jpg)..can any one help?

Comment: **screen shot is as below...**  Where it is?

Comment: hi vikas i for got to add here is the link  for screen shot  http://i.imgur.com/1Lg8B.jpg

Comment: vikas i followed ur blog and also posted this query in ur blog

Comment: Yes you can use a Custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` and Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox/4804366#4804366) answer to handle the CheckBox events.

Comment: but first i have to get entire phonebook with checkboxes eachrow.i am able to get all cotacts from phone book using ContactsContract.Contacts...i want to place checkboxes  each row ...can u post the entire code

Comment: Did you solve the problem vijaya?

Answer (score 0):

Use a TableView and an adapter to retrieve the contacts and then implement each row in your table. See the code below.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/