# CheckBoxes in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

hi i am using checkboxes with listview in android when i am scrolling listitem i am not getting the same checkboxes checked what are expected please help me in figuring out where i am wrong. when i select frst check box and scroll its give me second checkbox as checked and other output are also strange.here is my code

```
class base extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return price.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v=arg1;
j=arg0;
            LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
            v=li.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            txt.setText(author.get(arg0));
            TextView txt1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            txt1.setText(price.get(arg0));
            TextView txt2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtv);
        txt2.setText(title.get(arg0));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_forward);


        img.setImageBitmap(bit.get(arg0));
        CheckBox check1=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check);
        if(check[j]!=null)
            if(check[j]==true)
            check1.setChecked(true);
            else check1.setChecked(false);

        check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg2==true)
                //  Toast.makeText(SimpleActivity.this,arg0+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                check[j]= true;
                else 
                    check[j]=false;
            }

        });

            return v;


    }
        }
```

please help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list-v/7738854#7738854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are recycling your views each time, the checkbox will have the same value as the previous view of the listview.   What I would do is set the checkbox to false FIRST for every iteration and THEN figure out whether or not it should be checked:

```
check1.setChecked(false);
if(check[j]!=null && check[j]==true){
        check1.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's probably because the Adapter `getView()` method is calling `onCheckedChanged()` (only when reused Views are of opposite value). This leads to strange behaviour.

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
  if(check[j]==true) check1.setChecked(true); // will automatically call onCheckedChanged 
  else check1.setChecked(false);              // if check1 was previously the opposite

}
```

You should perhaps cancel checkListener before changing values so:

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

  check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); // first remove listener

  //update values
  if(check[j]==true) check1.setChecked(true); //no more side effect
  else check1.setChecked(false);

  //reinstall listener
  check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     //your code.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with ListView with CheckBox.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox/4804366#4804366) you can find a complete solution to this issue.