# CursorAdapter + CheckBox, if check some item, some other is checked too

Tags: android, adapter, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I try create my own Adapter for ListView with checkboxes on each row. All works fine, but problem is, when I check some checkbox and then scroll down, other one is checked too.

(When I check first, 11th, 21th, ..., is checked too) Can me anyone explain wher is the problem?

Thank you.

My adapter:

```
public class WordAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public WordAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags){
        super(context, cursor, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View oldView, Context ctx, Cursor c) {

        int wordQuestionIndex = c.getColumnIndex( WordDBAdapter.QUESTION );
        int wordAnswerIndex = c.getColumnIndex( WordDBAdapter.ANSWER );
        int activeIndex = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex( WordDBAdapter.ACTIVE ));
        String question = c.getString(wordQuestionIndex);
        String answer = c.getString(wordAnswerIndex);
        int active = c.getInt(activeIndex);

        Log.d("WordAdapter", "isActive: "+ active + " - " + question + ", " + answer);

        ((TextView) oldView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_question)).setText(question);
        ((TextView) oldView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_answer)).setText(answer);
        CheckBox checkBox =(CheckBox) oldView.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);
        //checkBox.setChecked(vh.isChecked);
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor c, ViewGroup root) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word, root, false);
        return view;
    }   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: CursorAdapter, ListView and CheckBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the reuse of the old view...

I would suggest, you maintain a list of check boxes items which are ticked and reset the check box item in bindview every time you initialize with new values..

Similar Question and solution is [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox)