# Repetition of checked items in checkbox in ListView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to incorporate a list of items that has a checkbox before each item much like in gmail. The problem is that when I check an item, another item in the next view created also gets checked i.e. this get repeated over and over in fixed intervals. How can I stop this repetition?

Comment: for this code requires.post your code so that i can help you.

Comment: You have missed the else condition.You may write code for if checkbox is checked and you may missed the code for if not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain the states of all checkbox.refer this link [Android: CursorAdapter, ListView and CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox/4804366#4804366)