# How to select only one checkbox in Adapter's getView()

Tags: android, android-listview

```
cbChecked.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FaxDialogActivity.record.get(position).isChecked = true;
            }
        });
```

but when i check the one checkbox, multiple checkboxes get selected after scrolling the listview.

Comment: ha evu thae koy var.!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because getview is called everytime the view recycles while scrolling a list view.So u have store a value and check it in getview to get checked checkbox.

Try this

1> Create an ArrayList of Boolean Object to store the state of the each CheckBox
2> Initializes the ArrayList items to default value false, means no CheckBox is checked yet.
3>When you click on CheckBox. Set a check against Checked/Unchecked state and store that value in ArrayList.

Now set that position to CheckBox using setChecked() method.

for complete code please refer [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox/4804366#4804366) and this [BLOG](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)