# listiview with checkbox doesn't work with shared preferences to store and read checkbox chekked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio, checkbox

i have a problem:if i check a checkbox and after i click on another tab and after i cambeback to previous tab, the checkbox before checkked now is not checked...
Maybe i wrong to use shared preferences...ANY IDEA?

THANKS IN ADVANCE! 
I HOPE IN YOU!

ADAPTER cLASS:

```
  public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

{

  private List<Planet> planetList;
  private Context context;
  ArrayList<Birra> objects;
    SharedPreferences settings;

    public  PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {

      super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      this.planetList = planetList;
      this.context = context;
  }




    public  class PlanetHolder  {
      public TextView planetName;
      public TextView distView;
      public TextView valuta;
      public CheckBox chkBox;
      public EditText edit;
      //public String quantità;
       // private boolean checked;





    }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View row = convertView;
      PlanetHolder holder = null;

      if (row == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
          row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
          holder = new PlanetHolder();
          holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
          holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
          holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
          holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
          holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
          holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
          row.setTag(holder);

      } else {
          holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
      }
       final Planet p = planetList.get(position);

      final SharedPreferences settingss = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     boolean Checked= settingss.getBoolean("Material", false);
      if(Checked) {
          //boolean Checked= settings.getBoolean("Material", false);
          holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
          System.out.println(Checked);
      }else{

          holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
          System.out.println(Checked);
      }

      final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;



      /*holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);


                  SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  settings.edit().putBoolean("Material", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                  System.out.println("presa");



                  finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                      @Override
                      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                          p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());


                      }
                  });
              } else {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                  finalHolder.edit.setText(null);

              }

          }
      });
*/
     // final SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);



                  settings.edit().putBoolean("Material", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                  System.out.println("presa");
              } else {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                  finalHolder.edit.setText(null);

              }

          }
      });


      finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
          }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          }

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());


          }
      });


      holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
      holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
      holder.valuta.setText(""+p.getValuta());
      holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
      holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
      holder.edit.setEnabled(false);



      return row;
  }



    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
      ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
      for (Planet p : planetList) {
          if (p.selected)
              box.add(p);
      }
      return box;
  }


    }
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;

    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        /*mSharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean mIsChecked = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("zao", false);
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(mIsChecked);*/

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();
        //plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4, "€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                    p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };

        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }




    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//*
        }*/

    }


    public void showResult(View v) {
        String  result2 = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount2=0;

        String a="";
        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()){

            if (b.selected){

                result2 += "\n" + b.name+" "+b.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount2+=b.distance * quantitaInt;
                //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
    /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.selected){

                result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }*/
      //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
        bun2.putString("scelta", result);
        TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();


        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putString("totale", a);
        TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
        transaction.commit();
*/













    }



}
```

Comment: this is how you need to deal with listview with checkboxes http://stackoverflow.com/a/37044624/2032561

Comment: use this link :-http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/android-listview/android-listview-with-checkbox

Comment: mmmm no......i don't need of your link,sorry.....

Comment: Try to use Database instead of shared preference for storing check box value, fetch from database when you switch tab and set using adapter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how store and read with shared preferences checkbox checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169103/how-store-and-read-with-shared-preferences-checkbox-checked)