# multiple selection in custom list view without check box

Tags: android, list, android-activity, icons, custom-lists

I am having `custom listview` with an icon at right end,I have to select multiple items in `custom listview`, on selecting items I have to replace that icon with another icons and when I click the replaced icon again I need to get previous icon.
[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbZrP.png)

```
 if (convertView == null){
            convertView = mlayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_of_waitlist_providers,null);
            tvProviderName = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provider_name);
            tvProviderSuburb = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provider_suburb);
            tvProviderCity = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provider_city);
            tvProviderPostCode = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provider_post_code);
            icAdd = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ic_add_provider);
        }
        s = map.get("providerName");
        tvProviderName.setText(s);
        tvProviderSuburb.setText(map.get("suburb"));
        tvProviderCity.setText(map.get("city"));
        tvProviderPostCode.setText(map.get("postCode"));

        icAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                icAdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use POJO class implementation to manage selected items and if possible provide some code

Comment: visit this [Answer - 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179789/how-to-get-list-of-checked-contacts/37201604#37201604) or [Answer - 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038293/maintaining-checkbox-states-in-listview-with-cursoradapter/37044624#37044624)