# Android: ListView of CheckedTextView + SQLite, display checked rows with Adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, checkedtextview

I am trying to implement a very simple "todo" list.
I chose to use a ListView of CheckedTextView (with id checked_text), the ListView uses CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE of course.

Now, I am using the SQLite database to store the list items.

### To fill the list I have something like:

```
cursor = dbHelper.fetchAll();
startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] from = new String[] {  DbAdapter.NAME };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.checked_text };

SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
R.layout.todo_multi_row, cursor, from, to);
listView.setAdapter(notes);
```

---

This is working fine, it gets all the items in the DB and for each
item it creates a CheckedTextView with as text DbAdapter.NAME.

But what I really need is to get both the text, and the checked state,
and check the Rows accordingly.

Let's say I can get the state (as integer 0/1) from the DB using
DbAdapter.CHECKED.. how can I implement a cursor adapter that gets the
job done?

I searched everywhere (for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406937/android-save-checkbox-state-in-listview-with-cursor-adapter) which is a mess) but found nothing to solve this problem. Wah. 
It seemed so easy at first.

Thanks,
Stefano

---

@Bert F:
Thanks, this is the method I am using to fill my list:

```
private void fillData() {
        Log.d("LIST","fill");
        cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTodos();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { TodoDbAdapter.NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.checked_text };

        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.todo_multi_row, cursor, from, to);

        final SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder mViewBinder =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(
                        final View view,
                        final Cursor cursor,
                        final int columnIndex) {

                    Log.d("LIST",view +" "+cursor+" "+columnIndex);

                    CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) view;
                    Log.d("LIST","NAME: "+item.getText()+" State: "+item.isChecked());

                    return false;
                }
            };

        notes.setViewBinder(mViewBinder);
        listView.setAdapter(notes);
    }
```

Now, as a test I am just printing out what is happening.
If I add 1 element to the list what I see is:

```
02-12 14:45:35.913: DEBUG/LIST(22621): fill
02-12 14:45:35.933: DEBUG/LIST(22621): android.widget.CheckedTextView@479da398 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@479d98f0 2
02-12 14:45:35.933: DEBUG/LIST(22621): NAME:  State: false
02-12 14:45:35.933: DEBUG/LIST(22621): android.widget.CheckedTextView@479da398 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@479d98f0 2
02-12 14:45:35.943: DEBUG/LIST(22621): NAME: first item State: false
02-12 14:45:36.013: DEBUG/LIST(22621): android.widget.CheckedTextView@479dc6c0 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@479d98f0 2
02-12 14:45:36.013: DEBUG/LIST(22621): NAME:  State: false
02-12 14:45:36.223: DEBUG/LIST(22621): android.widget.CheckedTextView@479dc6c0 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@479d98f0 2
02-12 14:45:36.223: DEBUG/LIST(22621): NAME: first item State: false
```

And if I check it..

```
02-12 14:53:33.123: DEBUG/LIST(22621): android.widget.CheckedTextView@479dc6c0 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@479d98f0 2
02-12 14:53:33.123: DEBUG/LIST(22621): NAME: first item State: false
02-12 14:53:33.123: DEBUG/LIST(22621): android.widget.CheckedTextView@479da398 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@479d98f0 2
02-12 14:53:33.123: DEBUG/LIST(22621): NAME: first item State: false
```

Let aside the fact that it says it is not checked, why is it firing so many times ? I just have 1 item :I

---

EDIT: ugly solution

```
private void fillData() {
        Log.d("LIST","fill");
        cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTodos();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { TodoDbAdapter.NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.checked_text };

        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.todo_multi_row, cursor, from, to);

        final SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder mViewBinder =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(
                        final View view,
                        final Cursor cursor,
                        final int columnIndex) {

                     final int checkedIndex =
                         cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                                 TodoDbAdapter.CHECKED);

                     Log.d("LIST","VIEW: "+view+" NAME: "+cursor.getString(columnIndex)+" "+cursor.getInt(checkedIndex));

                    return false;
                }
            };

        notes.setViewBinder(mViewBinder);
        listView.setAdapter(notes);
    }
```

With 2 entry (first selected second not) when I load the list I have:

```
02-12 15:59:48.613: DEBUG/LIST(23533): fill
02-12 15:59:48.643: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a30ec0 NAME: test 1
02-12 15:59:48.653: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a30ec0 NAME: LOL 0
02-12 15:59:48.683: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a30ec0 NAME: test 1
02-12 15:59:48.683: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a331f8 NAME: LOL 0
02-12 15:59:48.713: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a35770 NAME: test 1
02-12 15:59:48.713: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a35770 NAME: LOL 0
02-12 15:59:48.783: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a35770 NAME: test 1
02-12 15:59:48.783: DEBUG/LIST(23533): VIEW: android.widget.CheckedTextView@47a35770 NAME: LOL 0
```

Cheers.

Comment: I'm really confused about why its calling so many times on the same view (3 times for 47a30ec0 and 4 times for 47a30ec0)?  Would think 2 times might be normal, but 3 times and then 4 times (maybe more in the future?) is really odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Implement a [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html).
2. Have the [ViewBinder.setViewValue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29) method check for when its called for the `DbAdapter.NAME` column or else have it check for the `R.id.checked_text`-type view.
3. When it called, but not for *not* the target column/view, have it return `false` so that the adapter will do bind the column/view the way it normally would.
4. When it called for the target column/view, have it set the text and checkbox for the `(CheckedTextView) view`. It should end up returning `true` so that adapter won't continue to attempt to bind the view itself.  Note that the cursor is available to access query data to determine whether to check the checkbox or not (`DbAdapter.CHECKED`).
5. Set your `ViewBinder` in your `SimpleCursorAdapter` via [setViewBinder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29)

Here's one of my ViewBinder implementations.  Its not for checboxes, rather its for doing some fancy formatting of a text view, but it should give you some idea for the approach:

```
private final SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder mViewBinder =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(
                final View view,
                final Cursor cursor,
                final int columnIndex) {
            final int latitudeColumnIndex =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        LocationDbAdapter.KEY_LATITUDE);
            final int addressStreet1ColumnIndex =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        LocationDbAdapter.KEY_ADDRESS_STREET1);

            if (columnIndex == latitudeColumnIndex) {

                final String text = formatCoordinates(cursor);
                ((TextView) view).setText(text);
                return true;

            } else if (columnIndex == addressStreet1ColumnIndex) {

                final String text = formatAddress(cursor);
                ((TextView) view).setText(text);
                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Bert, I have edited my question, can you explain why it's firing so many times ? I am probably doing something wrong with the handling of the list :S

Comment: @Stefano - seems like its getting called twice for 2 different views (2x2=4).  Calling on 2 different views == seems like either there's 2 items in the list or the callback being used on two different lists.  Calling twice on the same view == seems strange, but I don't know for sure that that's not the way it works - overall it shouldn't matter that its called twice on the same view.

Comment: Ok, so this approach would work if I had a textbox AND a checkbox - using CheckedTextView I have 2 columns (NAME and CHECKED) for 1 single element, when I instantiate the SimpleCursorAdapter in the "FROM" I have TodoDbAdapter.NAME and in the "TO" R.id.checked_text - Then how can I get the checked state inside the ViewBinder ? Should I move the cursor manually somehow to the other column ? Thanks

Comment: Scratch that, I solved it simply using Log.d("LIST","VIEW: "+view+" NAME: "+cursor.getString(columnIndex)+" "+cursor.getInt(checkedIndex)); :D It is a bit ugly, but seems to be working. Thanks. (editing the question now)

Comment: @Stefano - "Should I move the cursor manually somehow to the other column?" You shouldn't think of a cursor moving across columns, it only moves across rows.  Its fine to access a different/additional columns.  I do this in the example above when I check for the latitude column, but the formatCoordinates uses lat and long.  Similarly above, I look for the street column, but I format the entire address (street1, street2, city, state, zip). I wouldn't call it ugly.  The alternative would be for simple adapter to allow mult-column -> view mapping which would be very complex.

Comment: Ok, now the problem is that I am not able to select the checkbox O_O I tried to add inside the setViewValue: CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) view; item.setChecked(true); item.setSelected(true); listView.setItemChecked(listView.indexOfChild(item), true); three different ways but the checkbox won't appear checked :| meh

Comment: It seems the problem is listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); I'll just remove this and handle the clicks myself. Google should provide some more clear documentation on how to use (store/retrieve) this kind of lists, meh :)