# android ListView with checkBox

Tags: android

I am facing some problem with `ListView` , I have inflated a layout with check box and used Custom base adapter.

I have used `android:focusable="false"` under check box in layout.

My `ListView`  clicks works proper .But actually I want the respective check box to be checked on list-view click.

So,I can perform different functions on `onLongclick` or other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yuu can cast your view on

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            YourView yourView = (YourView)view;   
            Checkbox checkBox = (CheckBox)yourView.findViewById(R.id.yourcheckbox);

            checkBox.setChecked(true);
         }
     }    });
```

Comment: happy to help :) .. you can try to mark this answer as correct if you feel so :)

Comment: you don't need this line `YourView yourView = (YourView)view; `
onItemClickListener knows the  current view(item) (in the paramaters)
so this line `Checkbox checkBox = (CheckBox)yourView.findViewById(R.id.yourcheckbox);`
become `Checkbox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.yourcheckbox);`

Answer (score 1):

may this help you....
[1](http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311) [2](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/25/fancy-listviews-part-four/)
[3](http://appfulcrum.com/?p=281)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406937/android-save-checkbox-state-in-listview-with-cursor-adapter)