# Need to find whether checkbox in listview is checked or not

Tags: android

I have created listview using layoutinflator. Listview contains checkbox and textview for each row. I am displaying items in a listview with checkbox checked by default.I can check\uncheck these items.

Now on the same layout I have one button and under clickevent of this button I want to check which item has checkbox in checked state and which has not.

Can anybody have any idea how to check this?

My Inflator code is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    try {
        mydbadapter.open();
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.syncissue_row, null);
        }
        issue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.issuedescription);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.issueCheckBox);
        issue.setText(arrlstFaults.get(position));
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        mydbadapter.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mydbadapter.close();
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406937/android-save-checkbox-state-in-listview-with-cursor-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is not standard one, but you can go for it if you don't find any other alternative. 
you can update your `getView()` method something like bellow.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    try {
        mydbadapter.open();
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.syncissue_row, null);
        }
        issue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.issuedescription);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.issueCheckBox);
        issue.setText(arrlstFaults.get(position));
        // add bellow line
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(position));
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        mydbadapter.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mydbadapter.close();
    }
    return view;
}
```

and you can write listener for having event of check changed. something like bellow. you can maintain one Hashtable for storing the check status as shown bellow.

```
 Hashtable ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Boolean>();

class MyCheckedChangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    int position = -1;
    myCheckedChangeListener(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

   ht.put(position, isChecked);
}

}
```

I hope It will work for you.