# Android CheckedTextView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, checkedtextview

I have a `listview`  that contains a `checkedtextview`.  My app moves from the top of the list view to the bottom.  I want to check if the item is checked before calling an action.  If it is not checked I want to move to the next item in the list.

E.g.

Item 1 - Checked

item 2 - Checked

Item 3 - Not Checked

Item 4 - Checked

So, I want the app to process as follows:

Item 1

Item 2

Item 4.

I am not sure how to access the checked status of the item from the `listview` position.

The logic that I want is as follows:

```
Is Current Item checked?
Yes:
Call action
No:
Move to next item.
Reloop to top of void.
```

I will need something in there to stop an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution will be to use an `ArrayList` of positions.
When the user check/uncheck a `checkbox`, add/remove accordingly the position in your `ArrayList`.
Then when the user is over, just iterate through the list to know which position have been selected.

Comment: So, within the onclicklistener, build an array list of checked item positions?  Then, test the current item position against that list.  If it is in it, go ahead and action?  If it isn't, how do i reloop?

Comment: This question has been asked a lot, see here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408987/1635817

Answer (score 2):

**1.)** First create an array, what indicates the items checked state in your adapter

(assuming you extend the `BaseAdapter` class for this purpose):

```
private boolean [] itemsChecked = new boolean [getCount()];
```

**2.)** Then create an `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean checked)
    {
        Integer index = (Integer)button.getTag();
        itemsChecked[index] = checked;
    }
}
```

**3.)** In your adapters `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    /*...*/
    CheckBox checkBox = /*get the checkbox*/;
    checkbox.setTag(index); 
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    /*...*/
}
```

**4.)** In the `onClick()` method:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //just get the boolean array somehow
    boolean [] itemsChecked = adapter.getItemsCheckedArray(); 

    for(int i=0; i<itemsChecked.length; i++)
    {
        if(itemsChecked[i])
        {
            //the i th item was checked
        }
        else
        {
                //it isnt checked
        } 
    }
}
```