# Return checked state of checkbox in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android save Checkbox State in ListView with Cursor Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406937/android-save-checkbox-state-in-listview-with-cursor-adapter)

I have a `ListView`, where each item contains some `text(name,id)` and a checkbox.There is a button to get back from `ListView` page. So a user check some items and go back to previous page. There is also a button is this page to get back to `ListView` page. When he/she gets back, I want to show him/her which items he/she had selected earlier.

I know about `SharedPreferences`, but I don't want to use it as I don't want to save that state when user restarts the application. I only want it during application runtime. I do some job on it, save data which he has selected and also check it when he gets back. But I can't able to check the checkboxes. I hope someone would say what wrong I am doing here. I use checkbox from xml,not programmatically.

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;

    private final  Activity context;

    public static ArrayList<String> friendName=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> friendBirthdate=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> friendId=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> getSelectedFriendId;
    public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.list =  list ;
    }

    public static int count=0;
    static class ViewHolder 
    {
        protected TextView text, sub;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView ==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);

            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);

            viewHolder.text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            viewHolder.sub = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub);

            viewHolder.sub.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);

            if(SelectionPage.get_selectedFriendId()!=null)   //checking whether user checked something earlier
            {
                getSelectedFriendId=SelectionPage.get_selectedFriendId();   //get checked userid from when user selects something

                for( int x = 0 ; x < getSelectedFriendId.size() ; x++ )
                {
                    for(int a=0;a<list.size();a++)
                    {
                        if(list.get(a).getId().contains(getSelectedFriendId.get(x)))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText( context, "matched..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(true); //this doesn't check checkbox which is the problem!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked)
                {
                    Model element = (Model)viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();

                    if(buttonView.isChecked())
                    {
                        count++;

                        friendName.add(element.getName().toString());
                        friendBirthdate.add(element.getPlace().toString());
                        friendId.add(element.getId().toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        friendName.remove(element.getName().toString());
                        friendBirthdate.remove(element.getPlace().toString());
                        friendId.remove(element.getId().toString());
                        count--;
                    }
                }
            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

        } 
        else 
        {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.sub.setText( list.get(position).getPlace());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, is there a bunch of checkboxes in each ListView item, or is there one checkbox in each item. You also might not have to use ViewHolder, but that's more of a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes,there is one checkbox in each item of listview

Comment: Possible [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2406937/1050058)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for responding.I got answer myself after 2 hours playing with it.I bring some changes in checking which item was selected previous.Give my updated code below for those who faces same problem like me.

```
    if(SelectionPage.get_selectedFriendId()!=null)
    {
        String s=list.get(position).getId().toString();

        getSelectedFriendId=SelectionPage.get_selectedFriendId();

        for( int x = 0 ; x < getSelectedFriendId.size() ; x++ )
        {
            if(s.contains(getSelectedFriendId.get(x)))
            {
                Toast.makeText( context, "matched!..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is working fine for me, but when again I click on matched or selected checkbox it is not unselecting..it still remain selected. guide me @ridoy ...thanks

Comment: Simply you can check toogle() method or even write code, when the checkbox isChecked(), then make it's setChecked(false). I mean something like these things.

Answer (score 1):

Are you firing off code to refresh the listview after a view's content changes? You sometimes have to do that, otherwise a ListView does who knows what. There's a bunch of commands like invalidateViews() that can do this. Having the view in getView invalidate itself might also work

The code definitely could use optimization, but that's another topic